# Facebook Graph integration in eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-graph-api, shared-libraries

I have integrated facebook using 'facebook-android-sdk-4.18.0' in my Android studio project.

Now I want to convert same gradle project in eclipse Android project.

but i am not able to find facebook grape API lib jar or lib project.

Anyone have idea, is it available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got classes.jar from External libraries. I used same in Eclipse project.